# Get all possible letter combinations with more than 5 letters

Tags: ruby

This code successfully would make array with all possible letter combinations with 5 characters.

`a = ('aaaaa'..'zzzzz').to_a`

however, when I try to go for 6+ characters, it takes like 10 mins, and then kills the task. Is there any way for it to actually load without killing the task? Is it limited by hardware?

Comment: You are creating about 300 billion strings, each about 40 bytes (on a 64 bit platform) big (including headers and metadata), for a total of 11GB plus an array with 300 billion entries, each one pointer, i.e. 8 bytes, for another 2.3 GB. So, you're allocating about 14 gig of RAM before you even start doing some real work. [Those numbers are rough estimates for recent versions of YARV. Obviously, memory internals are not part of the public API and may change at any time without notice, and will thus differ between versions and much more between impls such as JRuby or Rubinius.]

Comment: @JörgWMittag: I think you mean 300 million, but yes, nice analysis.

Comment: Oh yeah. That American million/billion/trillion stuff got me confused, and I over-corrected :-D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are indeed limited by hardware. In oversimplified terms, there are two limitation that you are facing here - processing power and memory capacity.

The "[k-permutations of n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#k-permutations_of_n)" formula will tell us that you are trying to generate and process `26**6 = 308_915_776` elements.

`(x..y)` creates a [`Range`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Range.html), which knows how to generate all of its elements, but doesn't eagerly do so. When you call `Range#to_a` however, your processor tries to generate all those elements. After some time, the process runs out of memory and dies.

To avoid the memory restriction, you could instead take advantage of the fact that `Range` is also `Enumerable`. For example:

```
('aaaaaaa'..'zzzzzzz').each { |seven_letter_word| puts seven_letter_word }
```

will instantly start printing strings. Eventually (after a lot of waiting) it will loop through all of them.

However, note that this will let you bypass the memory restriction, but not the processing one. For that there are no shortcuts other than understand the specifics of the problem at hand.